# Mechanize can't find any forms on my webpage

Tags: python, mechanize, autologin

stackoverflow!
I recently started learning Python after primarily using C++ and Java for a couple of years, and I wanted to put my knowledge to the test by making a program that would come in really handy from time to time.

You see, my school uses an online scheduling service, Magister, to provide us with our day-to-day appointments in school and to tell us what classes we have at what time.

Now, I thought it would be really handy if I had a Windows Widget display my schedule on my desktop.
I researched the windows widgets a bit and decided I best use python for the task, and came across the mechanize library.

I have written some code, but there is a problem, however, because the program can't seem to find any forms! I have used some javascript in the developer console to check how many forms there are on the page and there is just the one for logging in, but it doesn't have a name of any sort, just a class, so I tried using

```
browser.select_form(nr=0)
```

but that gave me a `FormNotFoundException` so I tried using 
`br.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('class') == 'FormClassName')` instead, which gave me the same exception.

I tried making mechanize print all forms on the page but it just printed an empty list.

Any idea what the problem could be, and more importantly, how I could fix it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT--**

HTML of the form:

```
 <form class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
            <fieldset legend="">
                <div>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input class="type-text ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text" name="username" id="username" data-ng-model="credentials.Username" required="required" data-on-keyup="onLogin()" data-keys="[13]" tabindex="1" autocapitalize="off" data-sm-focus="false" data-sm-auto-fill="credentials.Username">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="type-text ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" type="password" name="password" id="password" data-ng-model="credentials.Password" required="required" data-on-keyup="onLogin()" data-keys="[13]" tabindex="2" data-sm-focus="true" data-sm-auto-fill="credentials.Password">
                </div>
                <div class="btn-row">
                    <span class="check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox ng-pristine ng-valid" name="remember" data-ng-model="credentials.Usernameremember" id="remember" tabindex="3"><label for="remember"><span></span>Remember username</label>
                    </span>
                    <a class="btn-pri" data-ng-click="onLogin()" tabindex="3">Inloggen</a>
                </div>
                <a class="end-link ng-hide" title="Please choose a different school" data-ng-show="showScholenkiezer" tabindex="4" href="magister://doorstarten_blokkeren=1">Please choose a different school</a>
                <a class="end-link account ng-hide" title="Can't access your account?" tabindex="4" data-ng-show="schoolinformatie.ToonPasswordVergetenOptie" data-ng-click="onForgotPassword();">Can't access your account?</a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The remainder of the page consists mostly of general styling as it's just a login page.
Any clue as to what the problem might be?

**EDIT 2--**

Also, here is the mechanize code I tried to use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

browser = Browser()
browser.open('SiteURL')
browser.select_form(nr = 0) # Or browser.select_form(predicate=lambda f: f.attrs.get('class') == 'ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required') but that didn't work either
browser.form['username'] = 'Username'
browser.form['password'] = 'Password'
browser.submit()
```

Stackoverflow doesn't keep the indentation but it's there.
I have since tried using the selenium webdriver module but that didn't work either so I deleted that code.

Comment: show us HTML of the page

Comment: I editted my answer and it now contains the form HTML. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I hope there is only one form on that page? and also post full mechanize code you wrote.

Comment: Added python code to the OP, and yep, that's the only form.

Comment: Can it be that the form isn't there in the first place, and loaded later on with javascript?

Comment: Is there a particular need as to why the log-in has to be emulated *browser-style*? I'm thinking it's much better to just emulate the POST request of the log-in.